# Create Document Term Matrix with N-Grams in R

Tags: r, nlp, tokenize, tm, n-gram

I am using "tm" package to create DocumentTermMatrix in R. It works well for one - gram but i am trying to create a DocumenttermMatrix of N-Grams(N = 3 for now) using tm package and tokenize_ngrams function from "tokenizers" package.
But im not able to create it.

I searched for possible solution but i didnt get much help.
For privacy reasons i can not share the data.
Here is what i have tried,

```
library(tm)  
library(tokenizers)
```

data is a dataframe with around 4.5k rows and 2 columns namely "doc_id" and "text"

```
data_corpus = Corpus(DataframeSource(data))
```

custom function for n-gram tokenization :

```
ngram_tokenizer = function(x){
  temp = tokenize_ngrams(x, n_min = 1, n = 3, stopwords = FALSE, ngram_delim = "_")
  return(temp)
}
```

control list for DTM creation :
1-gram

```
control_list_unigram = list(tokenize = "words",
                          removePunctuation = FALSE,
                          removeNumbers = FALSE, 
                          stopwords = stopwords("english"), 
                          tolower = T, 
                          stemming = T, 
                          weighting = function(x)
                            weightTf(x)
)
```

for N-gram tokenization

```
control_list_ngram = list(tokenize = ngram_tokenizer,
                    removePunctuation = FALSE,
                    removeNumbers = FALSE, 
                    stopwords = stopwords("english"), 
                    tolower = T, 
                    stemming = T, 
                    weighting = function(x)
                      weightTf(x)
                    )


dtm_unigram = DocumentTermMatrix(data_corpus, control_list_unigram)
dtm_ngram = DocumentTermMatrix(data_cropus, control_list_ngram)

dim(dtm_unigram)
dim(dtm_ngram)
```

The dimension of both the dtm's were same.
Please correct me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately tm has some quirks that are annoying and not always clear. First of all, tokenizing doesn't seem to work on corpera created `Corpus`. You need to use `VCorpus` for this.

So change the line `data_corpus = Corpus(DataframeSource(data))` to `data_corpus = VCorpus(DataframeSource(data))`.

That is one issue tackled. Now the corpus will work for tokenizing but now you will run into an issue with `tokenize_ngrams`. You will get the following error:

```
Input must be a character vector of any length or a list of character
  vectors, each of which has a length of 1.
```

when you run this line:`dtm_ngram = DocumentTermMatrix(data_cropus, control_list_ngram)`

To solve this, and not have a dependency on the tokenizer package, you can use the following function to tokenize the data.

```
NLP_tokenizer <- function(x) {
  unlist(lapply(ngrams(words(x), 1:3), paste, collapse = "_"), use.names = FALSE)
}
```

This uses the `ngrams` function from the NLP package which is loaded when you load the tm package. 1:3 tells it to create ngrams from 1 to 3 words. So your control_list_ngram should look like this:

```
control_list_ngram = list(tokenize = NLP_tokenizer,
                          removePunctuation = FALSE,
                          removeNumbers = FALSE, 
                          stopwords = stopwords("english"), 
                          tolower = T, 
                          stemming = T, 
                          weighting = function(x)
                            weightTf(x)
                          )
```

Personally I would use the [quanteda](https://quanteda.io/) package for all of this work. But for now this should help you.

Comment: I was looking something similar. I havent used Quanteda so far but I will definitely explore more about Quanteda. Thanks for the help !