# Failing to create DTM for n-grams in R

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, tm, n-gram

I've tried to apply [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53226662/13606305), but it doesn't work. I've used VCorpus to get the `docs_es` corpus.

```
docs_es<-readRDS("docs_es.rds")

tokenitzador<-function(x){
  unlist(lapply(ngrams(words(x),1:3),paste,collapse=" "),use.names=FALSE)
}

control_list_ngram<-list(tokenize=tokenitzador,wordLengths=c(1,Inf))
control_list_unigram<-list(tokenize="words",wordLengths=c(1,Inf))

dtm_ngram<-DocumentTermMatrix(docs_es,control_list_ngram)
dtm_unigram<-DocumentTermMatrix(docs_es,control_list_unigram)

dim(dtm_ngram)[2]
> 200460
dim(dtm_unigram)[2]
> 200460
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Should work. If I run the code on the crude dataset, included with tm (`data("crude")`) the dtm's are different and have different amount of columns. If it doesn't work on your side, please include a reproducible example that shows where it goes wrong.

Comment: It also works with the `crude` corpus, but not my own. Both are 200460 columns long.

Comment: Hence the need of a reproducible example to show where it fails. Are you sure your control lists are not the same by any chance?

Comment: I just wasn't using the `VCorpus` function, bur rather `Corpus` alone. My bad.